# What is better to use, hardcoded array or resources string array?

Tags: java, android

What is better to use in my android program:

in mainActivity.java:

```
String[] st = {"Value1","Value2"};
```

or

in mainActivity.java:

```
String[] st = (String[]) getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Array1);
```

And in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="Array1">
    <item >Value1</item>
    <item >Value2</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I will use the second approch, if you need to `localize` (translate it in more languages) your strings.

Answer (score 2):

The second solution is better, because you can use different languages later (english, german etc.) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

I will also suggest to use the 2nd one as others suggested. Additionally it also helps you, if in case you want to change the elements of the array or if you want to add/delete elements of the array. In this case you don't need to change the source code again and recompile it. Instead you just need to change the XML file only and its done.

Comment: but remember to change it in each language or you might get errors

Comment: but even if it is just change in XML file, still we have to generate the apk right ?